# DataTable pagination does not work

Tags: javascript, php, pagination, datatables

I'm use DataTable to display my data by serverSide mode and ajax.
Everything is okay, but pagination doesn't work.

[image]

You can review the codes as follow:

HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>folder/class/method'
        },
        processing: true,
        scrollY: 370,
        paging: true,
        bJQueryUI: true
    });
});
```

The data that returned from server (`JSON`) as following:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 1208,
    "recordsFiltered": 10,
    "data": [
        ["1", "pando", "rewar", "pando@hotmail.com"],
        ["2", "chori", "raon", "m_chori@hotmail.com"],
        ["3", "Gorbat", "horiz", "horiz_555@yahoo.com"],
        ["4", "martin", "sokza", "martin_em5@gmail.com"],
        ["5", "dooz", "solda", "solda_m@gmail.com"],
        ["6", "maro", "meza", "r_meza@hotmail.com"],
        ["7", "nod", "ion", "nod_eam@yahoo.com"],
        ["8", "kaz", "loob", "kaz_007@hotmail.com"],
        ["9", "Barbara", "Elliott", "adipiscing@nonmassanon.org"],
        ["10", "Kendall", "Nathaniel", "ante.blandit@scelerisque.edu"]
    ]
}
```

All components of DataTable work fine, but the pagination not.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with you filtering the result set down to 25 using that top drop-down menu. on the bottom it says showing 25 of 25 entries, filtered from 1208. It should be showing 25 of 1208.

Comment: @Mike: Good note of you, but the problem now is the `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` gets the data count from same source. I was think the `recordsTotal` = all rows in the table(ex: 1208), and `recordsFiltered` = the displayed data at a time (ex: 25). but now I changed to the same source (ex: 1208).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter `recordsFiltered` must be equal to `recordsTotal` unless user performed a search. See [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for more information on sent and received parameters.

Also make sure you're returning the same value of `draw` parameter in the response.  In [JSON response](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) value of `draw` parameter must match value of `draw` parameter from the [request](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters).

Comment: Thanks, I have got from the manual:  `recordsTotal` = "the total number of records in the database" and `recordsFiltered` = "the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data". honestly, I'm still don't understand the difference between them

Comment: @LionKing, if you search for a term `London`, for example, `recordsTotal` should still contain total number of all records while `recordsFiltered` should contain number of records with term `London` in it.

Comment: Now I'm understood the idea.